# Editor that shows links between archives

Tags: javascript, php, html, editor, text-editor

I just designed a web page using HTML, PHP, JavaScript, ...

In every page I imported some files and after months of editing code, I can't say if I ended up using some of these files. I know that Dreamweaver leaves me see what are linked, but it doesn't show if I'm actually using those files.

Any idea?

Comment: Please reword your question, is is not clear what you're asking about. What do you mean by "archive" and "related"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "files" and "linked"

Comment: So you want to know what files in your website have no incoming links?

Comment: No. For example, if I have <script src="file1.js"></script>, I want to know if I'am using some variable or function from "file1"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can suggest is to copy all your javascript code into one file and load that file in PHPStorm.

Then run 'Inspect code...' command. Than will give you all unused variables and functions and much more!!!